# NODE: npm ERR! Could not get cache stat on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, docker

I am running node and npm, installed with nvm inside a Docker container to run tests. NPM install is being run by a non-root user who has its own node installation. For some reason I have to call node like this... /home/user/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/node and npm like /home/user/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/npm... This caused problems and gave me a "/usr/bin/env" "node" does not exist, so I symlinked /home/user/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/node to /usr/bin/node and things started rolling again. But now I'm getting this strange error.

I searched this error and apparently no one has ever seen it before.

`npm ERR! Could not get cache stat`

Here is the full stack...

```
npm ERR! Could not get cache stat
npm ERR! Could not get cache stat
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.4-tinycore64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/jenkins/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.10
npm ERR! path /home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/<<address_to_private_repo>>/objects/pack/tmp_pack_GKEEeR
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, chown '/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/<<address_to_private_repo>>/objects/pack/tmp_pack_GKEEeR'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/schools.vidigami.com/npm-debug.log
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that issue will go away if your install process populates the env variable NODE_PATH which is used internally to identify the modules directory, as well as augment env var PATH used to find executables node and npm   Below are the steps for such a source code install

```
export NODE_PARENT=/some/desired/install/path_goes_here
export NODE_PARENT=/usr/local/bin/nodejs   # ONLY use if you MUST install as root (sudo)
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/nodejs-v0.10.33 # use if you want to install as yourself

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}

make
make install
```